# Deep Cloning a Product - Clone Standard Price and Custom Prices

Tags: apex, clone, pricebook, pricebookentry

I have created a Record Detail button to clone a Product's detail, a related list called Bill of Materials, and both the Standard PB Entry, and any Custom PB Entries.

If I remove the Custom PB Entry clone code, everything works as intended, however, if I save with the Custom PB Entries, it fails with the following log entry (which refers to the line `insert CustomPB;`).

```
Class.ProductDeepClone.DeepCloneProduct: line 127, column 1
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, This price definition already exists in this price book: []
```

Although I (sort of) understand the error, in as much as it's essentially the same Object (PBE), I am not sure why the insert is considered a duplicate, or more importantly how better write the code.

Thanks

APEX:

```
global class ProductDeepClone {

    webservice static string DeepCloneProduct(Id ProId){

        Product2 pro = [SELECT id,Name,Country__c,Width_mm__c
            FROM Product2 WHERE Id = :ProId];

        Product2 proCopy = pro.clone(false,true);

        proCopy.Name = 'RENAME ME - ' + pro.Name;

        proCopy.Country__c = pro.Country__c;
        proCopy.Width_mm__c = pro.Width_mm__c;

        insert proCopy;

        List<Bill_Of_Materials__c> boms = new List<Bill_Of_Materials__c>();
        for(Bill_Of_Materials__c b :[
            SELECT b.id,b.Product_Material__c,b.Quantity__c,b.Unit_Cost__c
            FROM Bill_Of_Materials__c b
            WHERE Product__c = :pro.Id]){

                Bill_Of_Materials__c bCopy = b.clone(false,true);
                bCopy.Product__c = proCopy.Id;
                boms.add(bCopy);
            }
        insert boms;

        List<PricebookEntry> standardPB = new List<PricebookEntry>();
        for(PricebookEntry spb :[

            SELECT 
                spb.id,
                spb.UseStandardPrice,
                spb.UnitPrice,
                spb.ProductCode,
                spb.Product2Id,
                spb.Pricebook2Id,
                spb.Pricebook2.IsStandard,
                spb.Name,
                spb.IsActive

            FROM PricebookEntry spb
            WHERE Pricebook2.IsStandard = TRUE
            AND Product2id = :pro.Id
            LIMIT 1]){

                PricebookEntry spbCopy = spb.clone(false,true);
                spbCopy.Product2id = proCopy.Id;
                standardPB.add(spbCopy);
            }
        insert standardPB;

        List<PricebookEntry> CustomPB = new List<PricebookEntry>();
        for(PricebookEntry p :[

            SELECT 
                p.id,
                p.UseStandardPrice,
                p.UnitPrice,
                p.ProductCode,
                p.Product2Id,
                p.Pricebook2Id,
                p.Name,
                p.IsActive

            FROM PricebookEntry p
            WHERE Product2id = :pro.Id]){

                PricebookEntry pCopy = p.clone(false,true);
                pCopy.Product2id = proCopy.Id;
                CustomPB.add(pCopy);
            }
        insert CustomPB;


        string resultId = Id.valueOf(proCopy.Id);
        return resultId;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you try `pro.clone(false,true, false, false);` ?

Comment: Hi Sagar, I dont follow, isn't that just preseriving the following - preserveReadonlyTimestamps, preserveAutonumber ??

Comment: can you check the ID of the cloned object using method getCloneSourceId() ?? whether it is coming same or different?

Comment: Hi Sagar, the clone process is working, however the line thats failing is 'Insert CustomPB;' So the ID is passing, however the insertion of the customPB is being treated as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to overcome this error, by adding a WHERE clause in the 2nd Pricebook entry list.

When adding the standard price to a cloned product I used `WHERE Pricebook2.IsStandard = TRUE`.

To avoid the duplication error, I specified that the custom pricebook had the reverse clause - `WHERE Pricebook2.IsStandard <> TRUE`

This seemed to work!